# Getting memory issues in Blackberry

Tags: html, cordova, memory-management, blackberry

I am developing a phonegap app using HTML, CSS, jquery in Blackberry and in this app, sometimes when I relaunch the app, I am getting memory alert and app gets quit. I have placed all images that I am using in a folder. How can I handle the memory issues?

Answer (score 2):

Even I am facing a similar issue of device memory low in my HTML5+Phonegap BB app.
I face this problem often in BB 6.0 device but in BB 7.0(9900) I haven't ran into this problem yet. 
On page 24 of the link posted by tennesha the BB memory architecture is briefly explained by tneil . I quote

"The amount of physically allocated memory varies between device models, but lets say on average it's approximately 40MB of RAM.  This amount of memory is allocated for both running WebKit (loading the engine into memory, running JavaScript, displaying pages, computing layout, scaling images, etc.) and also loading your content in the view.

All apps on the device share the same WebKit instance so everyone shares the same 40MB space.  Think of each app using a web view as creating a "virtual tab" in the same web kit instance."

Here's the link for your reference.hope this helps.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441/page/24

Hope they solve this issue at the earliest.

Comment: I think it is required to stop the caching of data in the device but how can it be done? I have not yet done such things before using javascript so don't know how to solve this memory issue:(

Comment: If you are using jquery ajax request then you can add "cache:false" attribute to prevent caching.

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache:false,...
});

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry has a memory leak issue that is not resolved as yet. I use to develop apps for blackbery using html 5 but pretty much gave up. The platform has too many issues and is not ready for html5 app develpment. You can follow this link and see if there is any thing useful you can garner from it: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441 . Oh and by the way dont expect to get much real help from blackberry with this.